# Optional trainling slash for optional slugs in POST route

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing

I am using Symfony 4.2. When I set a route with an optional parameter, can I still use the route without a trailing slash?

```
api_post:
    path: /api/drive/{slug?}
    controller: App\Controller\Api::load
    methods: POST
```

My problem is, that the above route works WITH a trailing slash only. 
This is quite obvious, because I set this slash right after the word "drive" in the path. But how can I make the trailing slash optional too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
api_post:
    path: /api/{drive}{slug?}
    controller: App\Controller\Api::load
    methods: POST
    requirements:
        drive: "drive?"
        slug: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
```

Since [by default the slash character is a route parameter separator](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/4.1/routing/slash_in_parameter.html), you need to rewrite the route so that the `drive` is a parameter that can optionally accept `/` as the last character.

I've used a simple regular expression for `slug`, you'd need to find one that works for your use case.

This is **not pretty at all**, but it works.

Personally, I would simply have two different routes:

```
api_post_root:
    path: /api/drive
    controller: App\Controller\Api::load
    methods: POST


api_post:
    path: /api/drive/{slug?}
    controller: App\Controller\Api::load
    methods: POST
```

Easier on the eyes, easier to understand, and you could even handle it with the same controller if you really wanted.

Comment: Thank you @yivi. I can't get in working. I had to change my sample a bit and I tried path: /{apidrive}{slug?} and requirements: apidrive: "api/drive/?" ... but if a add a slash to my url (/api/drive/) it's not found.

Comment: btw: it works if I remove the {slug?} from the path

Comment: it works if I make the slug not optional, and add this as a requirement for the slug: slug: "^$|^(!\/)"